# CUDA thread synchronization

Tags: cuda

I am a bit confused about synchronization.

1. Using `__syncthreads` you can synchronize threads in a block.This,
   (the use of `__syncthreads`) must be done only with shared memory? Or
   using shared memory with `__syncthreads` has best performance?
2. Generally, threads may only safely communicate with each other if
   and only if they exist within the same thread block, right? So, why
   don't we always use shared memory? Because it's not big enough?
   And, if we don't use shared memory how can we ensure that results
   are right?
3. I have a program that sometimes runs ok (I get the results) and
   sometimes i get 'nan' results without altering anything. Can that be
   a problem of synchronization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The use of `__syncthreads` does not involve shared memory, it only ensures synchronization within a block. But you need to synchronize threads when you want them to share data through shared memory.
2. We don't always use shared memory because it is quite small, and because it can slow down your application when badly used. This is due to potential **bank conflicts** when badly addressing shared memory. Moreover, recent architectures (from 2.0) implement shared memory in the same hardware area than cache. Thus, some seasoned CUDA developers recommend not to use shared memory and rely on the cache mechanisms only.
3. Can be. If you want to know whether it is a deadlock, try to increase the number of blocks you're using. If it is a deadlock, your GPU should freeze. If it is not, post your code, it will be easier for us to answer ;)

Comment: :Ok,thank you!Unfortunately i can't post the code.I am using maximum number of block and threads and runs ok.Now,if i alter some parameters in the code and then run it,it shows me nan values or it doesn't run.If i go back to the original values it still shows me nan or doesn't run!It should run with the original (tested) values.(I must mention that all of these in pycuda).

Comment: Nan can come from many sources. But if it used to run with some tested values, maybe your CUDA driver is responsible. Did you change it recently?

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11543632/pycuda-different-values-running-the-same-program
I haven't changed driver.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

__syncthreads() and shared memory are independent ideas, you don't need one to use the other. The only requirement for using __syncthreads() that comes to my mind is that all the threads must eventually arrive at the point in the code, otherwise your program will simply hang.

As for shared memory, yes it's probably a matter of size that you don't see it being used all the time. From my understanding shared memory is split amongst all blocks. For example,  to launch a kernel using a shared memory of 1kb with a 100 blocks will require 100kb which exceeds what is available on the SM.

Comment: Shared memory often involves `__syncthreads` to make sure data are available to other threads in the block.

Answer (score 0):

1. Although `shared memory` and `__syncthreads()` are independent concepts, but they often go hand in hand. Otherwise if threads operate independently, there is no need to use `__syncthreads()`.
2. Two aspects restrict the use of `shared memory`: 1). the size of `shared memory` is limited 2). to achieve best performance, you need to avoid bank conflict when using `shared memory`.
3. It could be due to the lack of `__syncthreads()`. Sometimes, using `shared memory` without `__syncthreads()` could lead to unpredictable results.